# Parsing Specific Date String

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, time

I have been trying to parse a specific date string to change it to another format.
Current Format:

```
Sep 17, 2013 9:24:02 AM
```

Desired Format:

```
09-17-2013 09:24
```

Note that the desired format is military time.

I have been attempting to parse the first time using this:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
try {
    Date date = parser.parse(cell3.getStringCellValue());
    t.time = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e("Bad","date");
    t.time = cell3.getStringCellValue();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The logs never show the error, so no Exception is being raised, but the date's remain in their original format. The issue is that t.time is assigned the date string in the original format.
So t.time is assigned Sep 17, 2013 9:24:02 AM  when I want it to be 09-17-2013 09:24 
Anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks, Mike

Comment: Question Resolved, it was an error on my part... the format works!

Answer (score 0):

`Date` doesnt have a format. It encapsulates the number of milliseconds since `1 January 1970 00:00:00`. The formatted variable is available as a String in the variable `t.time`

Comment: Question updated, t.time is not being assigned the updated format of the time, but the old one.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Where do you determine that its still in the old format (i.e. `Sep 17, 2013 9:24:02 AM`)?

Comment: Well I printed out the time in the log, and they are right! So the issue isn't in the formatting. Thanks!